# CakePHP problems with Hash::extract()

Tags: cakephp

So im having a problem with the Hash::extract.
I have a find method and get a result like this:

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Message"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["conversation_id"]=>
      string(2) "11"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to have it formated like this : array{11}
so i tried using

```
Hash::extract($cid, '{n}.Message.conversation_id');
```

But when using this i get the result in the form like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "11"
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  $array = array(array('Message'=>array('conversation_id'=> array(11,12,13) )));
  var_dump(Set::extract('/Message/conversation_id', $array));
```

prints=>

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 11
  1 => int 12
  2 => int 13
```

Comment: When i tried with that i get this result: 
array(0) {
}
I also tried this: Set::extract('{n}/Message/conversation_id', $cid); but then i get the same result as i got with the Hash::extract

Comment: try Set::extract('/Message/conversation_id', $array);

Comment: I cant see anything different there from what you wrote in your first answer

Comment: / before Message - I nee to see your full array to give you proper extraction

Comment: Okey, when trying with Set::extract('/Message/conversation_id', $cid); i get array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "11"
}

Comment: I might have been unclear in my question, that works when i only have 11 i want to get, but later on i will get more results so that i would want an array like: array{11,12,13...}, sorry if i was unclear in my question.

Comment: still this does work - if you want to retrieve this array{11,12,13...},

Comment: I added an entry to the table so that i get two values but using the echo end(); only gives me the last conversation_id not both of them

Comment: Keep in mind that `Set` class is deprecated since Cake v.2.2 in favour of `Hash`: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html